# java: what libraries are there to manage/monitor processes?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, monitoring

I am helping develop an application that needs to run several processes. I need to be able to start and stop the processes as well as monitor them. [JPPF](http://www.jppf.org/) provides the ability to do management and monitoring of JPPF jobs and nodes/servers that run those jobs, but that is all across JVMs. I'm trying to weigh other solutions for management/monitoring processes that may not all be JVMs. The library I am looking for would be preferable if it can be used in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this addresses your issue of running processes that are not JVMs, but you might be interested in looking at Akka library as an alternative to JPPF: http://akka.io/. It is mostly built for scala I think (not a bad thing!) but also has a java api.